# play-authenticate - getting user information on scala views or controller for logged in user

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I'm using Google via play-authenticate for authentication in my java application. This is my first play-framework application.

I need data of logged-in user on scala HTML page or controller. @currentAuth does not have user-name, which is there in GoogleAuthUser and is available during authentication.
Since authentication request is directly handled in play-authenticate, I dont get that information to set it on session.

What is the best way to make the user data available to scala views or controller for play-authenticate applications?
Examples are using @currentAuth, which only has provider name and Id, not the user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in an example application. Controller can have a static method that uses session information to fetch user information from session using [PlayAuthenticate.getUser(final Session session)](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/PlayAuthenticate.java)

```
public static User getLocalUser(final Session session) {
  final User localUser = User.findByAuthUserIdentity(PlayAuthenticate.getUser(session));
  return localUser;
}
```